# multicolumn div with specified height and scrollable vertically

Tags: html, css

Why is this div scrollable horizontally and not vertically?

```css
.parent{
column-count:4;
background:gold;
margin:5px;
height:99px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce elementum rhoncus ex venenatis auctor. Integer vel hendrerit massa. Nam non ipsum sodales, feugiat lorem ac, tristique magna. Sed hendrerit sem eu ante fermentum hendrerit. Suspendisse faucibus nisi laoreet orci lobortis pharetra. Mauris feugiat malesuada ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Fusce mattis finibus ex, eget volutpat dolor bibendum quis. Mauris consectetur sit amet urna at bibendum. 
</div>
```

What I need is:
- four columns
- specified height
- scrollable vertically

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/yu1r9veh/3/

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce elementum rhoncus         ex venenatis auctor. Integer vel hendrerit massa. Nam non ipsum sodales, feugiat lorem     ac, tristique magna. Sed hendrerit sem eu ante fermentum hendrerit. Suspendisse     faucibus nisi laoreet orci lobortis pharetra. Mauris feugiat malesuada ullamcorper.     Nulla facilisi. Fusce mattis finibus ex, eget volutpat dolor bibendum quis. Mauris     consectetur sit amet urna at bibendum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce elementum rhoncus ex venenatis auctor. Integer vel hendrerit massa. Nam non ipsum sodales, feugiat lorem  ac, tristique magna. Sed hendrerit sem eu ante fermentum hendrerit. Suspendissefaucibus nisi laoreet orci lobortis pharetra. Mauris feugiat malesuada ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Fusce mattis finibus ex, eget volutpat dolor bibendum quis. Mauri consectetur sit amet urna at bibendum. 
</div>
</div>
```

You need a child div that has the same height as its parent (or less), and put the overflow on the parent, with a min-height on the child div. The child div expends with its content thanks to its min-height, its parent's height doesn't change, so it has to scroll vertically to make the child's content accessible.

```
.parent {
height: 100px;
overflow-y: scroll
}
.child {
column-count: 4;
background: gold;
margin: 5px;
min-height: 100px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because your div's height is not exceeding the screen to make it scrollable , wrap the parent div inside another div (like main parent),then give a height (to main parent)which is lesser than the parent div.overflow y sscroll for main parent

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky because of the columns. You have to use a wrapper element with the height you want and apply bigger height to your parent class element

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce elementum rhoncus ex venenatis auctor. Integer vel hendrerit massa.  Nam non ipsum sodales, feugiat lorem ac, tristique magna. Sed hendrerit sem eu ante fermentum hendrerit. Suspendisse faucibus nisi laoreet orci lobortis pharetra. Mauris feugiat malesuada ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Fusce mattis finibus ex, eget volutpat dolor bibendum quis. Mauris consectetur sit amet urna at bibendum. 
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
height: 99px;
}

.parent {
column-count: 4;
background: gold;
margin: 5px;
height: 300px;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bksr6240/3/)